# Jqwidgets are not working in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqxwidgets

I'm trying to make use of jqwidgets in my project which is built under asp.net mvc4 concept, the below code gives me an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘dataAdapter’ of undefined", please bare in mind that below code is just an example demonstrating that something is wrong with my implementation of the components into my project.

```
@model KhoonehYab.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = new $.jqx.dataAdapter([]);
    });
</script>
```

The jquery version being used is 1.9 (added in bundle & loaded in _layout) & jqwidgets v2.8.1, also tried with other older versions of both and got the same error, it also happens for any other jqwidget libraries such as simplest one, jqxButton. I've been stuck over this for 2 days already and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any troubleshooting from you guys is appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is not just to include the scripts. The scripts in MVC4 should be in: @section scripts { }.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they work and there is a help topic which demonstrates that: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/asp.net-integration/asp.net-binding-to-sql-database-mvc4.htm. Point 11 from the topic is very important. There is also a download link in the topic so you can download the sample.

Comment: Yea I understand what you're saying and what I'm doing here is almost the same as point 11, according to their forum and the topic I opened there, all you need is to include the required js files and put your jqwidget script in document.ready function and it should work and the strange thing is I used it in another mvc4 project and it worked perfectly & I did the same thing here and it's not working for any of the components, I also put alerts in their libraries to track the code, it's loaded, my alerts are thrown but it just doesn't go into the jqx functions :\ I'm really confused ...

Comment: it is not just to include the scripts. The scripts in MVC4 should be in: @section scripts { }.

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you make a reply so I can accept it ?